# Inline declaring and assigning multiple variables

Tags: c#, variables

Is it possible to declare and immediately assign a single value to several variables of the same type in a single instruction?
I'm looking for a solution to reduce the amount of code so as not to repeat variable names several times.

I know we can use this:

```
string server, db, user, pwd = server = db = user = string.Empty
```

or this

```
string server, db, user, pwd;
server = db = user = pwd = string.Empty;
```

But those duplicate variables names.

I want to do it something like this:
`string server, db, user, pwd <= string.Empty;`
or this:
`var (server, db, user, pwd) = ("");`

Comment: No it’s not possible.

Comment: You're sacrificing readability & refactorability to reduce code. I don't think that would be a win.

Comment: @Enigmativity honestly `string server, db, user, pwd = server = db = user = string.Empty` isn't any more readable, IMHO.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain - Yes, that's what I'm saying. It's not readable.

Answer (score 3):

```cs
var (server, db, user, pwd) = ("", "", "", "");
// or
var (server, db, user, pwd) = (string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty);
```

But I don't think either is a good choice. Heck, I'd probably use a class (or record) to "group" those variables:

```cs
public record DbConnectionInfo(
  string Server, 
  string Database, 
  string User, 
  string Password
);
```

And then, if you insist on initializing the values to an empty string:

```cs
public record DbConnectionInfo(
  string Server = "", 
  string Database = "", 
  string User = "", 
  string Password = ""
);
```

Or:

```cs
public record DbConnectionInfo {
  public string Server {get; init; } = string.Empty; 
  public string Database {get; init; } = string.Empty; 
  public string User {get; init; } = string.Empty; 
  public string Password {get; init; } = string.Empty; 
};
```

And since a record/class goes in it's own file, all this "disappears" from the code where you're currently trying the assignment.

```cs
var connectioninfo = new DbConnectionInfo();
```

Comment: "`(string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty);`"  I think that is the duplication OP is talking about

Comment: OP is talking about duplicate **variable names** (`server`, `db`, `user`, `pwd`).

Comment: Or a `ConnectionStringBuilder` which already exists.

Comment: @Charlieface A `ConnectionStringBuilder` builds connectionstrings. From the context we're not sure what's going on with the "separate" variables. Yes, they may get used to build a connectionstring, they may also be used to be passed around to some other class that builds the connectionstring or stores the values in a json file or... whatever. Point is: A ConnectionStringBuilder is a "do-er", it _does_ something. Variables are... variables. All I did was group them into something more coherent.

Comment: Thanks for answers.
Indeed, the problem that I would like to solve a little more complicated. 
As an example, I gave several variables related to data for user authentication, but in fact there are many more variables that need to be declared and immediately initialized.
Moreover, each group of variables has its own type. that's why I was looking for the shortest way to write code

variant like: var (a, b, c) = ("", "", "") duplicates "" thats not what i am looking for, but yeah may be this is the shortest one.

Comment: As others have stated: shortest doesn't necessarily translate into most readable. It's a neat trick but I wouldn't use it in actual code.  It's even worse when you use it for "many more variables". Just don't. Because you _can_ doesn't mean you _should_. It's fun for codegolf maybe, but leave it there.